# If dnf can't find the best candidate for package dependency, how am I supposed to find out?

Tags: fedora, zfs, dnf

zfs requires zfs-kmod = 0.8.2 so obviously it knows what it needs except that zfs-kmod requires dkms which can't be found.

What dnf says:

```
cannot install the best candidate for the job
```

Sub-parts of this question:

1 . I can use "--nobest" but I believe that is very undiscriminating. Is it actually and truly safe to use "--nobest". What if it picks an ancient package with serious vulnerabilities??

2 . It says "nothing provides dkms >= 2.2.0.3 needed by zfs-dkms-0.8.2-1.fc28.noarch". Even if I go "--nobest", is the best way to go to search internet for the "dkms" package manually? DNF cannot find dkms.

3 . Bringing it all together, much like I said in (2) above, how can I fill in the dependencies that dnf can't find safely?

My situation that is much like many others:

```
sudo dnf install zfs

 Problem: package zfs-0.8.2-1.fc28.x86_64 requires zfs-kmod = 0.8.2, but none of the providers can be installed
  - cannot install the best candidate for the job
  - nothing provides dkms >= 2.2.0.3 needed by zfs-dkms-0.8.2-1.fc28.noarch
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)
```

Comment: Fedora 28 has been unsupported for quite some time which could mean that it's missing some of the files. For instance it may lack `dkms >= 2.2.0.3`. You may force install the packages via `rpm -ivh --nodeps [packages]` but it's not guaranteed to work.

Comment: You should probably upgrade to newer release -- Fedora 28 EOL was in May 2019 so it isn't suprising that package dependencies are "broken". Also ZFS is not in official Fedora repositories, are you using some third party repo?

Comment: @VojtechTrefny This install is super standard. No special repos. I will look into what I need to do on my end to upgrade. I will try to come back to post an answer the question because I'm afraid I will not be able to upgrade in the environment with the conditions I'm under.

Comment: You have a package, `zfs-dkms-0.8.2-1.fc28.noarch` which requires the dependency `dkms >= 2.2.0.3`.  Apparently, none of your configured repositories has a package that solves `dkms >= 2.2.0.3`.  Fedora 28 is EOL and your configured repositories may have dropped those packages, but it would have provided `dkms-2.5.0` if you can find an intact repository.  The command `dnf repolist` will show you currently configured repositories.